# Displaying only 5 picklist values out of 12 on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have apicklist field having 12 values, but I want to display only 5 out of the 12 on a VisualForce page. I don't want to use Record Type.

Comment: Hi kumar, welcome to SFSE, please take some time to visit [ask] in order to get familiar with the forum. Afterwards, please **[edit]** your question, as is it is most likely going to be closed

Comment: I'm kind of surprised by the close votes. The question may be confusingly phrased but I think it's clear enough what is being asked.

Comment: why are you surprised? the OP has clearly not shown any effort into resolving this on their own, has not demonstrated any research attempt, the post itself is simply asking a "how to question". i wouldnt be suprised if it is closed and the only reason there are no downvotes is most likely because the user is new

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`<apex:selectList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm#!) and simply hard-code the five values you wish to display with [`<apex:selectOption>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm) components. You don't need Apex for this.